# Limit when $n$ goes to $\infty$, $1^\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits

How can i show that this limit equals one.

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{1 + n^2}{3 + n^2}\right)^n = 1$$

Comment: Hint: consider $\lim(((1+n^2)/(3+n^2))^{n^2})^{1/n}$ and use $\lim\sqrt[n]{const}=1$.

Comment: Thank you, i solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{3+n^2}{1+n^2}\right)^{1+n^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac2{1+n^2}\right)^{1+n^2}=e^2,$$we have$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{3+n^2}{1+n^2}\right)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left(\frac{3+n^2}{1+n^2}\right)^{1+n^2}\right)^\frac{n}{1+n^2}=(e^2)^0=1.$$Therefore$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1+n^2}{3+n^2}\right)^n=\frac11=1.$$

Comment: Oooh sorry, there was a misteke. I edited my question.